# Hosting asp.net core Web API in Windows Service

Tags: asp.net-web-api, windows-services

I completed ASP.NET Core Web API application running as console.
Now I need to add ability to run it as Windows Service.

I was able to successfully run generic ASP.NET Core application (not Web API) as a Windows Service.
But no luck with luck with Web API.

Target platform is .NET 7 / Windows.

I spent plenty of time looking for solution and only relevant solution I did find is to use 3rd party Nssm tool, which is highly undesirable.

Comment: There is very little difference between a web api project and other asp.net web projects now. Have you tried following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: What is wrong with nssm?

Comment: NSSM will work but its sometimes flagged falsely by some anti virus

Answer (score 0):

Just use NSSM it will work. I am using same for long time.

Although I am looking for alternatives to NSSM.